# How to fetch data based on multiple key pair in Postgresql + Rails4

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.4

I have a table XYZ which has few columns in which, I need to filter out resultset based on Two columns (col1, col2) requested params

Request params like:

```
filter: [ {col1: val1, col2: val2 }, {col1: val11, col2: val12 }]
```

API request received a params which contains Array of Hash, each hash has pair which is a requested query filter. Here is my table structure and expected resultset

**Table**

```
id      col1    col2
----------------------
1       val1    val2
2       val11   val12
3       val21   val12
4       val1    val2
5       val33   val33
```

**Result should be**

```
id      col1    col2
--------------------
1       val1    val2
2       val11   val12
4       val1    val2
```

I have checked https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117767/postgresql-pattern-match-against-array-elements but don't understand.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IN` condition based on the values provided:

```
select *
from xyz
where (col1, col2) in ( ('val1', 'val2'), ('vall11', 'vall12') )
```

Comment: Your suggestion is good but need it in Rails way . This pattern is hard to generate in Rails[ ( ('val1', 'val2'), ('vall11', 'vall12') ) ].